# Javascript Class, access property callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have the following javascript class similar to this:

```
class ModalFormButton {

  constructor() {
    this.contactForm = new ContactForm();
    let utils = new Utils();
    this.$signupModal = $(utils.getModalTmpl());
  }

  loadContactForm() {
    this.$signupModal.modal();
    this.contactForm.load();
  }

  contactBtnHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let utils = new Utils();
    var $t = $(this),
        $modalTitle = $t.data('modal-title'),
        $modalFormId = $t.data('modal-form-id');

    $('body').append(this.$signupModal);
    this.$signupModal.find('.modal-title').html($modalTitle);
    this.$signupModal.find('.modal-body').load($t.attr('href') + ' #' + $modalFormId,this.loadContactForm);
  };

  registerHandlers() {
    $('.modal-form-btn').click(this.contactBtnHandler);
  };

  load() {
    this.registerHandlers();
  };
}
```

My problem is that when `contactBtnHandler` is called I don't have access to class properties because the context belongs to `modal-form-btn`.
I know I can solve this using an arrow function, but I am wondering about if its possible to separate in a function the logic in the callback (here is a short example but I have longer functions) in a way similar to the one I am using.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "*separate in a function the logic in the callback*" - an arrow function would be separated logic, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could do:

```
getHandler (){
  return e => {
    //this is ModalFormButton
  };
}
```

And then:

```
 $('.modal-form-btn').click(this.getHandler());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try binding "this" to your class in your callback handler

```
registerHandlers() {
    $('.modal-form-btn').click(this.contactBtnHandler.bind(this) );
  };
```

Comment: Yes,  binding should work